# Overlapping use of the issue of the class name,

Tags: javascript, jquery

When this function is executed, only the main board executes but the child node does not.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Code used in the figure above:

--> main node class

```
<div class="node node_root">
    <div class="node__text">main</div>
</div>
```

--> children node

```
<div class="node"> 
   <div class="node__text">a</div> 
</div>
```

--> alert function

```
$(".node").on("click",function () {
    alert("check");
});
```